# VFR library display specific pages but it shows blank gray scrollable area >?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, vfr-reader

I have successfully integrated VFR and its works fine,
But when I trying to display PDFs specific page no. it shows me blank scrollable area.

For example. I have a "General.pdf" which have 20 pages.

Problem: When I try to display pdf from page no. 5 to 12 ; so pdf page no lock on 12 but not lock on page 5 means if I trying to swipe right it reaches page 4, again swipe to page 3 and so on until it reaches page no 1. But all of these pages not shown just a scrollable grey area are swiped ?

How can I avoid this scrollable area ?